# Rails find the latest record with specific product_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I need to display one specific product that just been updated. There are several products that have the same product_id, I just need to take the one that has the latest updated_at date stamp. the code below just throws error, how to properly display that one product?

```
<% @featured.where(product_id:product.id, ":updated_at".last) %>
```

Comment: Have you tried something like: `@featured.where(product_id:product.id).order(:updated_at).first`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
<% @featured.where(product_id:product.id).order("updated_at DESC").first %>
```

Or

```
<% @featured.where(product_id:product.id).order("updated_at ASC").last %>
```

---

**Note:** 
It is recommended that the ID be unique.

I hope this helps! ;)

Comment: it does not yield anything? does it need to have something like "do |features| %> so i can populate some of its info like status <%= features.status %> ?

Comment: try to use your model (class) for search your item and set this result in a variable: <% @feature = Feature.where(product_id:product.id).order("updated_at ASC").last %>

Comment: After:
<%= @feature.status %>